# Hello, I'm creating this automation with selenium, and I came across this problem

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The code is complete and functional but not the way I need it because at this point it ends up collecting all the hrefs with the tag "a" and there are dozens present on the page, but I need you to perform the action in just three. Is there any way to limit the amount?

...enter code here
....

```
      **links_de_posts2 = []
        hrefs2 = navegador.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
        pic_hrefs2 = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in hrefs2]
        print("Encontrei as hrefs!!")
        time.sleep(3)
        for link in pic_hrefs2:
            try:
                if link.index("/p/") != -1:
                    
                    links_de_posts2.append(link)
            except:
                continue
                
        for pic_href in links_de_posts2:
            navegador.get(pic_href)
            time.sleep(5)**
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you are using a wrong locator. Can you share a link to the page you are working on and clarify what elements are you trying to access there?

Comment: So, the project is basically an automation for instagram where it makes likes. With this code above it's working it srools the page and collects all the hrefs with //p// then goes through one by one liking but I'm trying make him leave the like only on the first three photos in the line and finish the process! the link can be from any profile or hashtag example: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/